# Convert multidimentional array to a simple array

Tags: php, arrays

When print_r($my_array);

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => num1
            [label] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => num2
            [label] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => num3
            [label] => 
        )

)
```

Now I wonder how to create a new array variable to hold only 1 level with the following structure. e.g:

if print_r($new_array), it will show:

```
Array
(
    [0] => num1

    [1] => num2

    [2] => num3

)
```

Comment: what you have tried show your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `foreach()` and store value in new array

```
foreach($arr as $v) {
  $newarr[] = $v['value']; 
}
print_r($newarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$new = array_map(function($element){ return $element['value'] ; }, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `foreach` of $my_array and assign `value` to `$new_array` variable like

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($my_array as $array){
  $new_array[] = $array['value'];
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop thru the array as follows and push the desired elements into a new array.

```
$new_array = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($my_array);$i++) {
    array_push($new_array, $my_array[$i]['value']);
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

below can work:

```
foreach($my_array as $k => $v){

$new_array[] = $v['value'];

}

print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
    $new_array[] = $value['value'];
}
print_r($new_array);
```